# Are there any compliations of ancient/medieval Jewish comments on Scripture?

Tags: talmud-gemara, product-recommendation, tanach, midrash, commentaries

Is there any book or website where I can look up ancient/medieval Jewish teaching on any given verse in the Tanach to see what the Talmud, Midrash, Rashi, etc. says about the verse?  Something akin to [the Ancient Christian Commentary on Scripture](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0830814760)?

Comment: Sefaria? https://www.sefaria.org/texts

Comment: Mikra'ot Gedolot is an equivalent but like @Chatzkel mentioned, that's all available online on Sefaria, and most of the times in English.

Comment: Not exactly an answer, but the ArtScroll Tanach series contains an anthologized commentary from Talmudic, Midrashic, and Rabbinic sources for each book in the Tanach.

Comment: Adding to what was already suggested: a. The [Torat Chaim edition](https://mosadharavkook.com/shop/%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%AA-%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%97%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%94-%D7%97%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%99-%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94/)  on the Pentateuch, which has some commentaries not usually found in Mikraot Gedolot. As far as I know, it's only in Hebrew though. b. https://alhatorah.org/ has many classic commentators until the close of the 19th century on every verse in Tanach, plus targums. This is also only in Hebrew/Aramaic, as far as I know.